# Did not Send Invite to Existing Member

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

So I am testing out the Stack Overflow for Teams (SFFT), and I ran into an issue. I  removed myself as a member, (deactivated) and then had another administrator try to invite me again. When he checked on the invite status, it showed that the invite wasn't sent out.

[image]

When I tried to access the team's page, I got the following message.

[image]

Previously I was able to just type my email in there and I would be able to get back in. Any way to fix this? I cannot seem to figure out how to reverse this, I must be missing a step or two or something.

Comment: Reminds me of the one time I banned myself out of my IRC channel ...

Comment: Maybe a deactivated member is still a member, and should not be invited again, but just re-activated?

Comment: @DonQuiKong I hope it doesn't allow the last admin to remove or demote themselves.. going to try that later haha.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you! That was it.

Comment: @DonQuiKong you forced me to look for an `mIrc-Script` tag, alas.. there is none

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would like to apologize for making the question seem more urgent than it was. We were stumped trying to figure out how to add people back and forth.

Here is the solution, once a user is added, ***they are always members***. You just need to go to the *Inactive* menu option and *Reactivate user*.

You can get here by following these steps:

- As an admin, go to your team page
- Click on settings under your page logo
- Click on manage under the *Members* title
- Click on *Inactive* in the selection on the right, and select *Reactivate user*

[image]
[image]

Comment: I hope this gets improved. Since it sent 0 invites, it must know that the person is already a member, so I hope it becomes more intuitive

Comment: Since this is the case, maybe the status message should finish with a suggestion like `(To reactivate a deactivated member, visit your team settings <link to members page>)` if there are any deactivated members in the list.

Comment: Seems to me that the inability to _completely leave a group_ is a potential GDPR issue. Why is the member only hidden, not actually removed? Leave means leave!

Comment: Since a team is likely to be in a corporate environment just deactivating the user means that if they rejoin the company their account and data can be restored with little to no fuss on the admin's side. This ease of use and corporate need to avoid having others poke through their team to reattach the profile is a likely reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit we actually delete the `Users` row and any FK'ed data - the only thing we keep around are those integer FK relationships, so we can map a user back up to their posts and comments, if they rejoin a Team.  Early on (in 2008?), we decided to hard-delete users, instead of having a `DeletionDate` soft-delete mechanism on them, like we have on almost all other content, e.g. `Posts.DeletionDate`.

Comment: @JarrodDixon That's good to hear! I haven't really looked into this, so if you've already stated this somewhere please do feel free to ignore with my blessing, but otherwise I wonder whether this kind of thing warrants a mention in some declaration somewhere. It could well be in the privacy policy. Like everybody else, for my sins I haven't read it :P But ultimately a user ID still references a user so one might argue that this isn't a complete deletion if relationships between services/entities/whatevs are still recorded. _(cont.)_

Comment: _(cont.)_ It does sound like your fix -- though welcome -- merely makes the code aware of this fact rather than "correcting" it (if a change is indeed warranted; I'm not necessarily asserting that it is)

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed now; invites can be sent to inactive users, whether they were self-deactivated or deactivated by a Team Admin.